# why wont my script run in html using django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

My page isnt doing what i programmed the javascript to do is know the code i correct if i call expand() it works but not check()

```js
function check(i) {
  if (document.getElementById(i).style.visibility == "hidden") {
    expand(i);
  } else {
    collapse(i);
  }
}

function expand(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "visible";
}

function collapse(i) {
  document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<div id="brand" onclick="check('brand-show')"> brand </div>
<div class="brand-show" id="brand-show" style="visibility: hidden">dcdv</div>

<div id="brand" onclick="check('brand-show')"> brand </div>
<div class="brand-show" id="brand-show" style="visibility: hidden">dcdv</div>
```

Please help i cant get the onlick to work in django for some reason.

Comment: What's the error message saying?

Comment: The code in the question, converted to a runnable code snippet, does exactly what I expect it to.  Can you clarify in what way it's failing for you?

Comment: when i runserver it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with the Javascript at all.  This code snippet hides/shows when you click the "brand"

```js
function check(i){
  if (document.getElementById(i).style.visibility == "hidden"){
    expand(i);
  }
  else{
    collapse(i);
  }
}


function expand(i){
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "visible";
}
function collapse(i){
    document.getElementById(i).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<HTML>
<div id = "brand"   onclick="check('brand-show')"> brand </div>
<div class="brand-show" id = "brand-show" style="visibility: hidden" >dcdv </div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: when i runserver it doesnt work for some reason

Comment: Are you getting errors when loading the webpage from the server inside your browser's console?  Also is the HTML page served up exactly the same?